# Indicies of zero ranges in a zero-one matrix

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matlab

I am using Matlab for one of my projects. I am actually stuck at a point since some time now. Tried searching on google, but, not much success.

I have an array of 0s and 1s. Something like:

```
A = [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0];
```

I want to extract an array of indicies: `[x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, ..]`

Such that `x_1` is the index of start of first range of zeros. `x_2` is the index of end of first range of zeros.

`x_3` is the index of start of second range of zeros. `x_4` is the index of end of second range of zeros.

For the above example:

```
x_1 = 1, x_2 = 3
x_3 = 9, x_4 = 10
```

and so on.

Of course, I can do it by writing a simple loop. I am wondering if there is a more elegant (vectorized) way to solve this problem. I was thinking about something like prefix some, but, no luck as of now.

Thanks,

Anil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get your results in a single vector like you described above (i.e. `x = [x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 x_5 ...]`), then you can perform a second-order difference using the function [DIFF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/diff.html) and find the points greater than 0:

```
x = find(diff([1 A 1],2) > 0);
```

---

**EDIT:**

The above will work for the case when there are *at least* 2 zeroes in every string of zeroes. If you will have single zeroes appearing in `A`, the above can be modified to handle them like so:

```
diffA = diff([1 A 1],2);
[~,x] = find([diffA > 0; diffA == 2]);
```

In this case, a single zero value will create repeated indices in `x` (i.e. if `A` starts with a single zero, then `x(1)` and `x(2)` will both be 1).

Comment: @gnovice isn't the sort overkill? The starts and ends are already sorted with respect to themselves and each other, so they can simply be interleaved.

Comment: @MatlabSorter: In this case the two calls I make to FIND result in vectors of different lengths, so they can't simply be interleaved. If you separate out finding the starts and ends like you did, then interleaving is much easier.

Comment: @gnovice Actually, why not do x = find(diffA > 0 | diffA == 2)? One less find operation and it is already sorted. You'll only get a single entry for the opening, but a check of the first element seems necessary for all of these approaches anyway.

Comment: @MatlabSorter: Because that won't replicate the indices. The OP wants an index for the start *and* end of a string of zeroes to appear in `x`, and for a single zero these two numbers will be the same.

Comment: @MatlabSorter: I found a way to reformulate the solution so that I no longer have to sort and I make one less call to FIND.

Comment: @gnovice You're right about the single zeros, I missed that. Your new solution looks great.

Answer (score 3):

The diff function is great for this sort of stuff and pretty quick.

```
temp = diff(A);
Starts = find([A(1) == 0, temp==-1]);
Ends = find([temp == 1,A(end)==0])
```

Edit: Fixed the error in the Ends calculation caught by gnovice.

Comment: Just one small typo: you need to remove the `+1` when computing `Ends` to get the ending index the way the OP wants it.

Comment: Another problem: `Ends` will be missing the last ending index if `A` ends on a string of zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

Zeros not preceded by other zeros: `A==0 & [true A(1:(end-1))~=0]`

Zeros not followed by other zeros: `A==0 & [A(2:end)~=0 true]`

Use each of these plus `find` to get starts and ends of runs of zeros. Then, if you really want them in a single vector as you described, interleave them.